# Load additional CONFIG file with values

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am using lot's of values for my test like username and password.

For this purpose I created a config file where I store just this data in JSON, it looks like:

```
{
    "login": "test",
    "password": "pass",
    "number": "1234",
}
```

It works for me if I request it at start of each test file (one file for login, another for something else)

How can I load this config file for once and not in every single file.
Example, how I do it now:

```
var configFile = require('./config.json');
```

Can somebody help me to setup this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow the ["DRY" principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), use your protractor config and globally available [`browser`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor) object:

- in your protractor config, "import" your configuration file and set it as a `params` value:

  ```
  var config = require("./config.js");
  exports.config = {
      // ...

      params: config,

      // ...
  }
  ```
- in your tests, simply use `browser.params`, e.g.:

  ```
  describe('Logging in', function(){
       it('should log in', function(){
           var login = element(by.id("login"));
           login.sendKeys(browser.params.login);

           var password = element(by.id("password"));
           login.sendKeys(browser.params.password);

           element(by.id("submit")).click();
       });
   });
  ```

In other words, this is "Import once - use everywhere" approach.

Comment: Hi alecxe, 
thank you for your answer. Please can you be a bit more specific in first part ( maybe provide some real data example), I'm understand that I lod config file but not sure how to do that exprt.config part :)

Comment: @Andurit Sure! I'm assuming you know where your `protractor` config is located. In this config, you'll find `exports.config = {` part. Just before it, add a `require` call like provided in the answer. Inside the `require()` you should provide a path to your `config.json`.

Comment: it does make sense, just trying to add path to config.json which is located in:
'C:\Next\test\angular\e2e\specs'  from protractor.conf.js which is located in 'C:\Next' but var 'configFile = require('./test/angular/e2e/spec/config.json');' doesn't work

Comment: ConfigParser Error: Cannot find module 'test/angular/e2e/spec/config.json'

Comment: @alecxe what if I have multiple environments and different parameters for each env?

Answer (score 1):

You could simple use configFile as a global variable and use it in each of your tests.

```
describe('Description', function(){
    var configFile = require('./config.json');
    it('Test1', function(){
        //Consume configFile here
    });
    it('Test2', function(){
        //Consume configFile here
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi DroidArrrh, thank you for your answer. But I afriad this option require to have all tests in single file. And in my case I would like to try avoid this.